# Solaris 11.4 system header files prevent usage of stlport4 library

Tags: c++, build, solaris

Using this one line C++ program  with any Solaris Studio compiler, gives an error on Solaris 11.4 when using the -library=stlport4 option.

hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

$ /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC -m64 hello.cpp -o hello -library=stlport4

"/opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/include/CC/stlport4/stl/_stdio_file.h", line 161: Error: __pad is not a member of const __FILE.

"/opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/include/CC/stlport4/stl/_stdio_file.h", line 163: Error: __pad is not a member of const __FILE.

"/opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/include/CC/stlport4/stl/_stdio_file.h", line 165: Error: __pad is not a member of const __FILE.

"/opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/include/CC/stlport4/stl/_stdio_file.h", line 165: Error: __pad is not a member of const __FILE.
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [64-bit Solaris `FILE` structure is opaque](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E61689/advanced-43.html):

> 64-bit applications should not rely on having access to the members of the `FILE` data structure. Attempts to access private implementation-specific structure members directly can result in compilation errors. Existing 32-bit applications are unaffected by this change, but any direct usage of these structure members should be removed from all code.

You can't access the `FILE` structure when doing a 64-bit compile on Solaris.  It should work if you compile a 32-bit binary, though.

Why did Sun do this?

Because Sun (and now Oracle, for at least a bit longer) provide [actual binary compatibility ***guarantees***](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/solaris-guarantee-program-1426902.pdf):

> A binary application built on Solaris 2.6 or later that makes use of operating system interfaces as defined in stability.5 run on subsequent releases of Oracle Solaris, including their initial releases and all updates, even if the application has not been recompiled for those latest releases.

That's Oracle's guarantee.  Sun's long-ago guarantee was actually stronger, pretty much saying if your code compiled, no later update to Solaris would break it.

And early versions of Solaris had only an 8-bit field for the `FILE`'s associated file descriptor.  And that file descriptor field was visible, and code built on early versions of Solaris used it.

So Sun was stuck with an 8-bit field for the file descriptor in the `FILE` structure.

But that was over three decades ago - before 64-bit processors came about.

And there were no legacy 64-bit binaries Sun had to worry about being binary [forward-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility) with.

Since Sun only guaranteed ***binary*** compatibility, Sun made the new 64-bit `FILE` structure opaque so no compliant code could access it.  (Yes, Sun was providing 64-bit systems in the early 1990s. [My Little Pony](https://www.fakesteve.net/2010/02/my-little-pony-a-look-back.html) killed a great, innovative company.)

Sun did provide [an extended `FILE` library](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5175/extendedfile-5.html) that could be used by programs needing more than 256 `FILE`'s open at any one time:

> The extended FILE facility allows 32-bit processes to use any valid file descriptor with the standard I/O (see stdio(3C)) C library functions. Historically, 32-bit applications have been limited to using the first 256 numerical file descriptors for use with standard I/O streams. By using the extended FILE facility this limitation is lifted. Any valid file descriptor can be used with standard I/O.

In [Solaris 11.4 that now reads](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37853/extendedfile-7.html):

> The extendedFILE.so.1 is an obsolete, empty, library, kept for binary compatibility only.
>
> Its old purpose, the use of file descriptors larger than 255 for 32 bit binaries, is now the default behavior in Oracle Solaris.
>
> The libc library now handles the environment variables originally handled by extendedFILE.so.1

The bottom line is if you want to access the 64-bit `FILE` structure on Solaris, you're not going to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the stlport4 headers provided with the compiler, Oracle Bug 27531287.  Patches for Studio 12.3, 12.4, 12.5, and 12.6 are available to customers with current support contracts.

(Andrew Henle's answer explains the underlying problem, the stlport4 headers had depended on something they shouldn't have, and broke when that changed in Solaris 11.4.)